# syntax error function return value

Tags: go

```
func main(){
    ...

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", access_log(r))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("HTTP server: ", err)
    }
}

func access_log(r http.Handler) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Access log: ", err)
    }

    return handlers.LoggingHandler(io.Writer(f), r)
}
```

## error

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:71: access_log(r) used as value
./main.go:83: too many arguments to return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func access_log(r)` does not define the type for the parameter r.

Once you define it, the compilation should be able to proceed.

```
./main.go:83: too many arguments to return
```

The function as define as no return value, hence the error.

If you add the return type of [handlers#LoggingHandler](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#LoggingHandler), that would be  `http.Handler`.

```
func access_log(r) http.Handler {
   ...
   // Then you can return:
   return handlers.LoggingHandler(io.Writer(f), r)
}
```

Comment: @clarkk you  can't currently as defined: see my edited answer.

Comment: I have defined the `r` argument.. have updated my question and error

Comment: you don't need to define type of function arguments? have added the return type.. Now there are no errors.. But nothing is logged to the file.. The file is created though

Comment: @clarkk Yes, I have answered the original question. Why nothing is logged would be a separate question.